# Is it valid to use the separable ODE technique?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I have the following equation on a given support:
$\frac{d}{dx} G(h(x))=\frac{G(h(x))}{1-h(x)}h'(x)$.

I am trying to deal with the equation by the following steps:

$\frac{\frac{d}{dx} G(h(x))}{G(h(x))}=\frac{h'(x)}{1-h(x)}$ and then take integration on both sides.

I am wondering whether I am allowed to apply the the separable ODE technique to this equation.

Comment: If you apply implicit differentiation on the LHS, you can get rid of the $h'(x)$ term.

Comment: Yes, but this equation is attained from other equations including the differentiation (chain rule) on the LHS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Separation of variables would be appropriate....

$${d\over dx} G(h(x))={G(h(x))\over 1-h(x)}\cdot h'(x)$$

$${dG\over dh}\cdot h'(x)={G(h(x))\over 1-h(x)}\cdot h'(x)$$

Assuming $h'(x) \not=0$ yields;

$${dG \over dh}={G(h)\over 1-h} \implies {dG \over G(h)}={dh\over(1-h)}$$

From here the path to the solution is obvious....